# Role of probability in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, probability

In any machine learning example say linear regression, the objective is sometimes two-fold. One to optimize some analytical function like squared error and one is to optimize some probability function. Is there a  relation between these two objectives? If it is, what is that?

Comment: Linear regression is not a machine learning technique, it's a statistical one. I think you mean "predictive analysis" instead of "machine learning" (they are not synonymous). Other than that, I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @Digio The claim that "linear regression is not a machine learning technique" is not, in my opinion, a very useful one to make. Of course it originated in the statistical community long before there was such a thing as machine learning, but it can be analyzed or used in the same way as any so-called "machine learning technique" — and the distinctions here are all quite fuzzy and ultimately not very informative.

Comment: @Digio I think it is a machine learning algorithm. We try to learn pattern in the data which can predict y (continuous number in this case) given x. So I think the question is quite clear.

Comment: Linear regression does not "learn" from data. A human expert assumes a model and uses a mathematical method to fit the data, whereas in ML an algorithm builds a model dynamically through training - this makes a huge difference. Most people think that machine learning is another catchy name for statistics but this is far from the truth. ML and statistics share the objective of prediction-making but they're not the same discipline. I could go on forever about this but the point is that for me to understand your question I needed to know whether you meant prediction-making on ML or on statistics.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but again that will be true for all ML algos. In SVM we assume a linear model and then fit the data, in logistic regression we assume logistic model and fit the data and so on. I think for any ML algo you have to assume some model apriori and then fit the data on it. There is no way to search for all possible models and select the best one. I am not trying to counter your argument. It might be correct, I am just putting my perspective to it.

Comment: That's a fine observation but keep in mind that the euclidean concept of linear separability is not the same as the algebraic concept of a linear function. A hyperplane in a linearly separable ambient space may not necessarily reflect a linear relationship between its objects. In other words, the model which linearly separates your data in its feature space, is not necessary a linear function of your features. In fact, the actual Perceptron model (logistic regression) which maps your X to your y is not linear in nature at all.

Comment: [continued] Multi-layer perceptron and Kernel SVM don't assume linearity at all. In general, machine learning methods are called "black box" because you don't get to see nor choose the underlying predictive model. This makes sense if you consider that they were designed to be integrated within machines (hence the name) and for that they had to be fully automated. The idea with ML is that you focus on prediction, not on inference as in the case of statistics. You don't care about what drivers led to a certain decision, you only care about making the best decision (e.g. in image recognition).

Answer (score 3):

You can often relate cost functions, like the squared error function, to probability density functions by the relation

$$p(w|D) = \frac{1}{Z(D)} e^{-f(w, D)}$$
where $w$ is the set of parameters, you want to learn, $D$ is the observed training data, $f$ is the cost function and $Z$ is a normalization term that keeps sure the density integrates to one. You can see that the cost function is the negative (unnormalized) log density.

In that way you can relate a squared error to a Gaussian distribution on your parameters, the ridge regression regularizer to a Gaussian prior, and many more. Minmizing your cost function is then equal to finding the maximum likelihood estimate of your density.

Comment: Note that by definition, any likelihood or posterior probability you maximize can be viewed as a cost function, though not all cost functions can be interpreted probabilistically.

Comment: Thanks Dougal. That helped. It was pretty confusing reading ML algo's in two fold. One to optimize cost function to learn the parameters, other talking in terms of probability distributions, maximum likelihood and all that. It was difficult to relate both of these.

Comment: @Dougal Is SVM the exceptional case you are mentioning. I mean who's cost function has no probabilistic component?

Comment: @SHASHANKGUPTA It [can be related](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2763-a-probabilistic-interpretation-of-svms-with-an-application-to-unbalanced-classification.pdf), but yes, it's complicated.